# How test correctly the LoginForm through @WithAnonymousUser

Tags: spring, spring-security, spring-mvc-test

About `Spring Security`

For the class that extends `WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter` I have the following for the `configure` method:

```
        .and()
        .formLogin()
            .loginPage("/perfom/login")
            .loginProcessingUrl("/perform_/login")
            .usernameParameter("username")//default
            .passwordParameter("password")//default
            .defaultSuccessUrl("/welcome")
            .failureUrl("/perfom/login?error") //default is /login?error
            .permitAll()
```

It works fine in runtime. Until here no problems.

When `Spring MVC Test` plays I have the following:

```
@Before
public void setUp(){
    mockMvc = MockMvcBuilders.webAppContextSetup(webApplicationContext)
                             .apply(springSecurity())
                             .build();
}

@Test
@WithAnonymousUser
public void saveOneHtmlGetForNonAuthenticatedPrincipalTest() throws Exception {

    resultActions = mockMvc.perform(get(url).with(csrf().asHeader()).accept(MediaType.TEXT_HTML_VALUE)
                                            .header("Accept-Language", ClientUserLocale.ENGLISH.getLocale().toString())).andDo(print());

    resultActions.andExpect(status().isFound())
                 .andExpect(redirectedUrl("/perfom/login"));
}
```

The test fails with the following error message:

```
java.lang.AssertionError: 
Redirected URL expected:</perfom/login> 
but was:<http://localhost/perfom/login>
```

Not sure if it is the expected behavior or something missing, not sure why
`http://localhost/`appears.

Comment: I think it is expected. That is how org.springframework.security.web.authentication.LoginUrlAuthenticationEntryPoint  builds redirect URL for login form. It always builds absolute URL based on the information from the original request. Probably it is related with the specification of the redirect's location URI.

Comment: @manuel-jordan, I have the same problem. Did you find a solution?

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem and was able to fix it using `redirectedUrlPattern`.

In your case the solution should be:

```
.andExpect(redirectedUrlPattern("**/perfom/login"))
```

Comment: Let me test it soon as I can. Thanks